# Offset origin when using FillRect

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, canvas, draw

I draw a rectangle using FillRect(0,0,100,100). I also added a function that logs the x and y coordinate when I click on the screen. I noticed that the topleft corner of the rectangle isn't (0, 0) but there is an offset. It is (8,8). Anyone has an idea what is causing this ? I could of course solve it by making (-8,-8) as starting point but that is just a weird solution, You should just expect that the rectangle should start at (0,0).

Comment: Your <body> has an 8px margin

Comment: @Kaiido Nice catch, this is assuming OP ofc must not have tried `fillRect(-8, -8, 100, 100)` since they'd still see a gap if it's being caused by a default margin.

Comment: Thx, Kaido. 

Yes, I didn't try the fillrect(-8,-8, .. ) :-)